# Accessing config.yml variables in Bolt extensions

Tags: bolt-cms

I've set up a clean extension and am trying to pull in info from the extension's config.yml file. Config.yml is placed inside the extension folder (at the same level as Extension.php).

At the moment I'm just testing to see if I can retrieve the config. Here's the whole Extension.php:

```
<?php

namespace Bolt\Extension\andyjessop\vimeo;

use Bolt\Events\CronEvent;
use Bolt\Events\CronEvents;

use Bolt\Application;
use Bolt\BaseExtension;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Extension extends BaseExtension
{

    public function initialize() {

        $this->app->get('api/update_video_content', array($this, 'updateVideoContent'))
                  ->bind('updateVideoContent');

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "vimeo";
    }

    public function updateVideoContent()
    {
        $config = $this->config['user_id'];
        $response = $this->app->json($config);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

And in the config.yml:

```
access_token: xxxxxxxx
user_id: xxxx
api_base_url: https://api.vimeo.com/
```

But it returns an empty object. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your config called `Config.yml.dist` or `config.yml.dist` - note the capital C, it should be all lowercase? Other than that, after installation of your extension the `config.yml.dist` will be copied to `app/config/extensions/{extensionname}.config.yml` and the values in there will be used.